# Windows блокирует доступ к файловой системе FAT32

Tags: c++, windows, файловая-система, fat32

Мне нужно дописать программу, которая уже написана под Windows на с++. Задача в том, чтобы из системы FAT32 стирать имя удаленного файла (делаю безопасное удаление, чтобы программы восстановления не давали инфы о том, что файл с таким-то названием был вообще на компьютере). Это легко получается сделать используя WinHex.

У меня есть алгоритм, вполне рабочий, но проблема в ОС, которая блокирует доступ в таблице FAT. Смех в том, что система позволяет писать что угодно от нулевого до, кажется, около 10-титысячного смещения, из-за чего раздел можно очень легко положить, но в таблицу доступа не дает, не смотря на то, что запускаюсь от имени администратора.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <filesystem>
#include <iomanip>
#include <sstream>
#include <Dbt.h>



int main() {
setlocale(LC_ALL, "rus");
//Путь к диску U:, его открытие     L"\\\\.\\PhysicalDrive0\\Partition2";

//Путь к разделу через физический диск
LPCSTR partitionU = "\\\\.\\U:";
//const wchar_t* partitionU = L"\\\\.\\U:";

HANDLE hDisk = CreateFileA(partitionU, 
    GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE  , NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, 0, NULL);

if (hDisk == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
    std::cout << GetLastError() << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
else std::cout << "Success!" << std::endl;
//****************************************
    if (SetFilePointer(hDisk, 4194304, NULL, FILE_BEGIN) == INVALID_SET_FILE_POINTER) {
        std::cerr << "Ошибка установки указателя: ";
        return GetLastError();
    }

    byte buffer[512*1]; //кол-во секторов *n
    DWORD dwRead;

    int sector_count = 0;
    int row_count = 0;
    int str_count = 0;

    if (ReadFile(hDisk, buffer, sizeof(buffer), &dwRead, NULL)) {
        std::cout << "Прочитано байт:" << dwRead << std::endl;
        for (DWORD i = 0; i < dwRead; ++i) {
            if (row_count != 15) {
                std::cout << std::hex << std::setw(2) << std::setfill('0') << static_cast<int>(buffer[i]) << " ";
                row_count++;
            }
            else {
                std::cout << std::hex << std::setw(2) << std::setfill('0') << static_cast<int>(buffer[i]) << " "<<std::endl; 
                row_count = 0;
                sector_count++;
            }
            if (sector_count == 32) {
                std::cout << "-----------------------" << str_count++ << "------------------------" << std::endl;
                sector_count = 0;
            }
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
    else {
        //std::cerr << "Ошибка при чтении: " << GetLastError() << std::endl;
        DWORD error = GetLastError();
        std::cerr << "Error opening disk. Error code: " << error << std::endl;
    }
//*********************************

//**********Переписывание данных*********
byte* pointer = reinterpret_cast<byte*>(0);
LARGE_INTEGER largeInt;
largeInt.QuadPart = 0x400200;//reinterpret_cast<LONG_PTR>(pointer);

if (!SetFilePointerEx(hDisk, largeInt, NULL, FILE_BEGIN)) { //file_begin - от начала файла
    std::cerr << "Ошибка установки указателя: ";
    return GetLastError();
}

DWORD dwBytesWritten = 0;
//const char dataToWrite[] = "\xd2";
// Создаем массив из 512 значений
unsigned char byteArray[512*1];
// Заполняем массив нужными значениями, например, 0xFF
memset(byteArray, 0xFF, sizeof(byteArray));


if (WriteFile(hDisk, byteArray , sizeof(byteArray), &dwBytesWritten, NULL)) {
    std::cout << "Данные успешно записаны. Байтов записано: " << dwBytesWritten << std::endl;
}
else {
    std::cerr << "Ошибка при записи данных: " << GetLastError() << std::endl;
    DWORD error = GetLastError();
    std::cerr << "Error opening disk. Error code: " << error << std::endl;
}

//**************************************




//**************************************

CloseHandle(hDisk);
return 0;
}
```

Для лучшего понимания картины прикладываю скрины:

1. Создаю файл[image: Создаю файл]
2. Так он выглядит до удаления. После там будем чепуха[image: Так он выглядит до удаления]
3. Recuva после удаления находит такой след, а его быть не должно[image: Recuva после удаления находит такой след, а его быть не должно!]

4.Нахожу его название в таблице (метка E5 говорит о том, что файл удалён)[image: Нахожу его название в таблице]

5.Вношу немного чепухи и сохраняю (это WinHex)[image: Вношу немного чепухи и сохраняю (это WinHex)]

6.И вот теперь Recuva выдаёт требуемый мне результат, которого я не могу добиться алгоритмом[image: И вот теперь Recuva выдаёт требуемый мне результат, которого я не могу добиться алгоритмом]

Comment: Ну как вам это удается? 8-0 Перезапись какой-то ерундой, переименование, удаление - и *у меня на флешке FAT32* Recuva ничего такого не находит - кроме переименованного удаленного файла...

Comment: На каком именно этапе ошибка? Что возвращает `GetLastError()`?

Comment: @PRODIGY , ошибка в самом конце, на моменте записи. 'GetLastError()' возвращает 5 - Access denied.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Так, разобрался. Для того, чтобы код заработал, нужно размонтировать образ путём:                  `DeviceIoControl(hDisk, FSCTL_LOCK_VOLUME, NULL, 0, NULL, 0, &dwBytesWritten, NULL); DeviceIoControl(hDisk, FSCTL_DISMOUNT_VOLUME, 0, 0, 0, 0, &dwBytesWritten, 0);`

сделать запись, затем снова его смонтировать (либо он сам смонтируется как только прога завершит работу). Монтаж происходит путём закрытия дескиптора носителя:

`CloseHandle(hDisk);`

Answer (score 1):

> Так, разобрался

На мой взгляд это не полное решение проблемы, т.к. в общем случае, помимо блокировки тома, запись в служебные сектора FS диска требует соблюдения следующих правил:

1. Поскольку ОС активно взаимодействует с FS, операции записи должны быть асинхронными, для чего предусмотрена структура "OVERLAPPED" в параметрах `CreateFile()`. Перед каждым вызовом функций `Read/WriteFile()`, структуру "OVERLAPPED" нужно очищать, а в её поле "Offset" указывать новое смещение (для томов это номер сектора). Пример открытия тома: `FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED | FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL`.
2. По умолчанию, для операций в/в с дисками включено кэширование, которое имеет смысл отключить. Для этого служат флаги `FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING` (без буфера) + `FILE_FLAG_WRITE_THROUGH` (сквозная запись в кэш, и сразу на диск). Их нужно скомбинировать с флагами из пункта(1).
3. В критических случаях ОС может залочить доступ к служебной области FS, тогда придётся использовать указанный вами `DeviceIoControl()` с кодом "FSCTL_LOCK_VOLUME". Детали здесь: https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows/win32/fileio/volume-management-control-codes